# ToPagedListAsync() - The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider

Tags: linq, asynchronous, model-view-controller

I have been trying to sort out this for hours and could not find a solution.
I am using a Web Api MVC project and trying to convert an IEnumerable list to a paged list async. I'm able to compile but I'm still getting a runtime error on the ToPagedListAsync() line.

> The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068."

1st Layer:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MatchingCriteria>> GetMatchingCriterias(int id)
{
     return await _ctx.MatchingCriterias.Include(mc => mc.RuleDefinition).Where(mc => mc.RuleDefinitionId == id).ToListAsync();
}
```

2nd Layer:

```
internal async Task<IEnumerable<MatchingCriteria>> GetMatchingCriterias(int id)
{
    using (CrawlerDbContext db = new CrawlerDbContext())
    {
    var matchCriteriaMgr = new MatchingCriteriaManager(db);
    return await matchCriteriaMgr.GetMatchingCriterias(id);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? id, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page){
    var matchingCriterias = await _crawlerProvider.GetMatchingCriterias(id.Value);

    //...
    IQueryable<MatchingCriteria> matchCrit = matchingCriterias.AsQueryable();
    //Error here -> return View(await matchCrit.ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

if I do instead in the controller:

```
var matchingCriterias = _db.MatchingCriterias.Include(mc => mc.RuleDefinition);
```

then:

```
return View(await matchingCriterias.ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize)
```

That works well!

I could return a DbSet on the nested methods but I could not use the ToListAsync() in the 1st layer;

Is there a way to make the list IQueryable?
Any other ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it myself by creating an AsyncQueryable extension as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking#async)

Then I could call the pagedListAsync() method like bellow:

```
return View(await matchingCriterias.AsAsyncQueryable().ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize)
```